# Sorting method with Object Literal not producing same results as same logic using Switch/Case syntax - Typescript

Tags: typescript, sorting, material-ui, switch-statement, object-literal

I've have a sort method for a Material Table that works the way I want with a **switch** statement, but I want to use the same logic with Object literals, when I converted the code the sorted data is not coming in the correct order (either ascending or descending).

```
sortExpensesWithSwitch(sort: Sort): void {
    switch (sort.active) {
      case 'id': // sort on id
        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
          (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
            sort.direction === 'asc' ? a.id - b.id : b.id - a.id // descending
        );
        break;
      case 'employeeid': // sort on employeeid
        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
          (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
            sort.direction === 'asc'
              ? a.employeeid - b.employeeid
              : b.employeeid - a.employeeid // descending
        );
        break;
      case 'dateincurred': // sort on dateincurred
        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
          (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
            sort.direction === 'asc'
              ? a.dateincurred < b.dateincurred
                ? -1
                : 1
              : b.dateincurred < a.dateincurred // descending
              ? -1
              : 1
        );
        break;
    }
  } // sortExpenseData

  sortExpensesWithObjectLiterals(sort: Sort): void {
    const literals = {
      // sort on id
      id: (this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
        (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
          sort.direction === 'asc' ? a.id - b.id : b.id - a.id // descending
      )),
      // sort on employeeid
      employeeid: (this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
        (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
          sort.direction === 'asc'
            ? a.employeeid - b.employeeid
            : b.employeeid - a.employeeid // descending
      )),
      // sort on dateincurred
      dateincurred: (this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort(
        (a: Expense, b: Expense) =>
          sort.direction === 'asc'
            ? a.dateincurred < b.dateincurred
              ? -1
              : 1
            : b.dateincurred < a.dateincurred // descending
            ? -1
            : 1
      )),
    };
    literals[sort.active as keyof typeof literals];
  } // sortExpensesWithObjectLiterals
```

The literal way is producing: 1,3,2,4,5,6,7,9 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 that the switch way produces. The sort.active as keyof... code is producing the correct property name value.

am I missing a conversion somewhere? any help is appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't the values in the object be functions, for example? all the statements are being executed on the object definition. Anyway, that does not happen if you use immutable/functional expressions.

Comment: right... I just changed it to use functional expressions and it seems to work now, thanks for pointing that out.